# WP_Query: Filter tax_query OR meta_query

Tags: wordpress

How can I combine the result of the tax_query and meta_query?

ex:
tax_query results to:
Post1, Post2.

and meta_query results to:
Post3.

I want to combine the results of the 2 queries.
Here is my partial code:

```
'tax_query' => array(
     'relation' => 'AND',
     array(
         'taxonomy' => 'tax1',
         'field'    => 'term_id',
         'terms'    => array(1,2,3),
     ),
     array(
         'taxonomy' => 'tax2',
         'field'    => 'term_id',
         'terms'    => array(1,2,3),
     ),
 ),
 'meta_query' => array(
     array(
         'key'     => 'meta1',
         'value'   => '1',
         'compare' => '=',
      ), 
 ),
```

The same question was asked here but wasn't answered. So I'm re-opening it.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you wanting it to act like an 'OR' where a post that matches _either_ the tax_query or meta_query is returned? AFAIK that's not possible using WP_Query, I just had a quick look [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query) but you might want to have a more detailed look just in case. You _might_ need to [write a custom database call](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb). What was the other question you are referring to?

Comment: thanks @TimMalone. that made things clear. What i did was i just queried them separetely and its done.

Comment: No problem @japhfortin, glad that helped you! I've added it as an answer to help future visitors as well. If you feel it solved it for you, feel free to mark the answer as accepted using the check mark on the left of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are wanting it to act like an 'OR' where a post that matches either the `tax_query` or `meta_query` is returned.

Unfortunately, that's not possible using [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

You'll either need to write a [custom database call](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb), or just query them separately and do your checking on the PHP end (that's ok if you know you'll have a relatively small number of results, but be warned this won't necessarily scale to a huge site).

Answer (score 2):

The only way to achieve a query like that is creating a custom query to the db using the `$wpdb` global and SQL statements. I think it would be something like this:

```
global $wpdb;
$querystr = 
"
SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy as term_taxonomy1 ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = term_taxonomy1.term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy as term_taxonomy2 ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = term_taxonomy2.term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms as tax1_term1 ON(term_taxonomy1.term_id = tax1_term1.term_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms as tax1_term2 ON(term_taxonomy1.term_id = tax1_term2.term_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms as tax1_term3 ON(term_taxonomy1.term_id = tax1_term3.term_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms as tax2_term1 ON(term_taxonomy2.term_id = tax2_term1.term_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms as tax2_term2 ON(term_taxonomy2.term_id = tax2_term2.term_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms as tax2_term3 ON(term_taxonomy2.term_id = tax2_term3.term_id)
WHERE 
(
    (
        (term_taxonomy1.taxonomy = 'tax1') 
        AND 
        (tax1_term1.term_id = 1 AND tax1_term2.term_id = 2 AND tax1_term3.term_id = 3)
    )
    OR
    (
        (term_taxonomy2.taxonomy = 'tax2') 
        AND 
        (tax2_term1.term_id = 1 AND tax2_term2.term_id = 2 AND tax2_term3.term_id = 3)
    )
)
OR
(
    $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'meta1' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = '1'
)
ORDER BY $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value ASC
"
$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

Then you could iterate over `$pageposts` as with a `WP_Query` loop.